# Como Hago para Mostrar los Mensajes de Alerta a un Costado de la Pantalla de Manera que no se Superpongan unos Sobre otros

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpinejs

Estoy configurando un componente en Laravel con Blade que envíe mensajes de error como los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando hay más de un error las alertas se superponen unas a las otras y no se observa, sino la primera, las demás quedan ocultas como se ve en la imagen anterior.

He intentado varias configuraciones con Alpinejs y con JavaScript, pero no he podido lograr separar visualmente en pantalla las Alertas de forma que se vean una debajo de la otra, pero que se vean todas.

El último código que utilice con Alpinejs fue el siguiente:

```js
@if ($messages)
    <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'fixed top-0 right-0 mt-3 mr-3 space-y-2 z-50']) }}>
        @foreach ((array) $messages as $key => $message)
            <div class="flex p-4 mb-4 text-white bg-red-500 border-t-4 border-red-700 rounded-lg shadow-lg" role="alert" x-data="{ show: false }" x-show="show" x-transition x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true; setTimeout(() => show = false, 5000); }, {{ $key }} * 6000); $nextTick(() => $el.style.transform = 'translateY(' + ({{ $key }} * ($el.offsetHeight + 16)) + 'px)')">
                <svg class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                <button @click="show = false" class="ml-auto text-lg font-semibold">&times;</button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Después, intente con un script de JavaScript, pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, aquí dejo el código:

```js
@if ($messages)
    <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'fixed top-0 right-0 mt-3 mr-3 space-y-2 z-50']) }} id="alert-container">
        @foreach ((array) $messages as $key => $message)
            <div id="alert-{{ $key }}" class="alert hidden flex p-4 mb-4 text-white bg-red-500 border-t-4 border-red-700 rounded-lg shadow-lg" role="alert">
                <svg class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
                    {{ $message }}
                </div>
                <button onclick="hideAlert({{ $key }})" class="ml-auto text-lg font-semibold">&times;</button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <script>
        function showAlert(key, delay) {
            const alertElement = document.getElementById('alert-' + key);
            alertElement.classList.remove('hidden');

            const alerts = document.getElementsByClassName('alert');
            let offsetY = 0;

            for (let i = 0; i < key; i++) {
                offsetY += alerts[i].offsetHeight + 16;
            }

            alertElement.style.transform = 'translateY(' + offsetY + 'px)';

            setTimeout(() => {
                hideAlert(key);
            }, delay);
        }

        function hideAlert(key) {
            const alertElement = document.getElementById('alert-' + key);
            alertElement.classList.add('hidden');
        }

        @foreach ((array) $messages as $key => $message)
            setTimeout(() => {
                showAlert({{ $key }}, 5000);
            }, {{ $key }} * 6000);
        @endforeach
    </script>
@endif
```

Agradezco su ayuda, para indicarme que debo corregir en el código y así ver las alertas en pantalla una debajo de la otra sin superponerse. Gracias.

Comment: no soy experto.. pero hay un fixed ahi y un top 0 que me parece que traban todo?

Comment: Intente quitando ambos, después el fixed solamente y posteriormente el top 0 solamente, pero ninguno soluciono nada. Siguen apareciendo superpuestos.